# I'm always getting false for is_authenticate() in Django

Tags: python, django, authentication

I'm  trying to do email authentication for users who successfully logged in and redirect them to the respective homepages based on their role. The login is working, I'm getting the otp in mail and otp authentication is also working fine and the user is redirected to the correct homepage.

However I realised that one is able to directly access the homepage from the url in browser, even if not logged in. I tried `@login_required` decorator before the homepages view, but for some reasons it was not working and redirects me to login page even if the user is already logged in, so I tried the below way, but now the `is_authenticated` is always giving me false.

```
def reader_home(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
    return render(request, 'reader_home.html', {'username': request.session.get('username')})
else:
    messages.info(request, 'User is not yet authenticated!')
    return redirect('homepage')

def writer_home(request):
    print(f'request.user:{request.user}')
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, 'writer_home.html', {'username':request.session.get('username')})
    else:
        messages.info(request, 'User is not yet authenticated!')
        return redirect('homepage')
```

The below is the login_view and otp-verification view:

login_view:

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        role = request.POST.get('role')
        try:
            user = UserCredentials.objects.get(username=username, role=role)
        except UserCredentials.DoesNotExist:
            user = None
        if user:
            if user.check_password(password):

                login(request, user)

                otp_secret = pyotp.random_base32()
                otp_secret_bytes = base64.b32encode(otp_secret.encode())
                totp = TOTP(secret=otp_secret_bytes,period=180)
                otp = totp.generate()

                request.session['otp_secret'] = otp
                request.session['username'] = username


                # Send email with OTP
                subject = 'Login OTP'
                html_message = render_to_string('otp_email.html', {'otp': otp})
                plain_message = strip_tags(html_message)
                from_email = 'microtales00@gmail.com'
                to_email = [user.email]
                send_mail(subject, plain_message, from_email, to_email, html_message=html_message)

                return redirect('otp_verification',role,username)
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Invalid Password!')
                return render(request, 'login.html')

        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Invalid UserName or Role!')
            return render(request, 'login.html')

    return render(request, 'login.html')`
```

otp_verification:

```
def otp_verification(request, role,username):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        entered_otp = request.POST.get('otp') #string type
        otp_secret = request.session.get('otp_secret')# int type
        print(f'entered_otp: {entered_otp}')
        print(f'otp_secret:{otp_secret}')
        if not otp_secret:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid request')

        if str(entered_otp) == str(otp_secret):

            if role == 'writer':
                return redirect('writer_home')
            elif role == 'reader':
                return redirect('reader_home',username)
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Unknown Role!')
                return render(request, 'login.html')
        else:
            # OTP verification failed
            messages.error(request, 'Invalid OTP. Please try again.')
            return render(request, 'otp_verification.html')
    return render(request, 'otp_verification.html')
```

I have the below configs in `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'tales.apps.TalesConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_otp',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

and here is the app `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from tales import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.homepage, name='homepage'),
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
    path('logout/', views.logout_view, name='logout'),
    path('login/', views.login_view, name='login'),
    path('otp-verification/<str:role>/<str:username>/', views.otp_verification, name='otp_verification'),
    path('reader_home/<str:username>/', views.reader_home, name='reader_home'),
    path('writer_home/', views.writer_home, name='writer_home'),
]
```

I don't have much in templates, just basic html with basic styles, using only username for welcome note.

Comment: Please fix indentation.